# Why can't we use a single pointer in function parameters of append/insert function in singly linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

So I have been learning data structures using pointers in C and I had this doubt of why we use double pointers as function parameters and why can't we use a single pointer in the append function in a singly linked list?(Still a beginner)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    struct node
    {
        int number;
        struct node *next;
    };
    void insert(struct node **q,int value)//this is the part where I have the doubt
{
    struct node *temp,*r;
    temp=*q;
    if(*q==NULL)
    {       
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->number=value;
        temp->next=NULL;
        *q=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=*q;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
        r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r->number=value;
        r->next=NULL;
        temp->next=r;
    }
}
void print(struct node *temp)
{
    printf("\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp->number);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head=NULL;
    insert(&head,10);//call by reference
    insert(&head,20);//call by reference
    insert(&head,30);//call by reference
    insert(&head,40);//call by reference
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine,
but when I use **single pointer as a parameter**, it executes but there is no output.
Here is the single pointer parameter version of the insert/append function.
Basically **Why doesn't it work with a single pointer?**, Why do we need to use a double pointer as parameter to make it work?

````
void insert(struct node *q,int value)
{
    struct node *temp,*r;
    temp=q;
    if(q==NULL)
    {       
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->number=value;
        temp->next=NULL;
        q=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=q;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
        r=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r->number=value;
        r->next=NULL;
        temp->next=r;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Within the function you are trying to change the pointer to the head node of the list.

If the function will accept the pointer by value as in your second function definition then the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original pointer to the head node. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer. The original pointer will be unchanged.

You can imagine the (second) function definition and its call the following way.

```
struct node *head;
head=NULL;

insert( head, 10 );
//...

void insert( /*struct node *q,int value */ )
{
    struct node *q = head;
    int value = 10;
    //..
```

As you can see the function deals with its own local variable `q` (function parameters are function local variables) that has a copy of the value of the pointer `head` defined in main. So within the function it is the local variable `q` that gets a new value. The value of the pointer head is not being changed.

So you need to pass the pointer by reference. In C passing by reference an object means passing a pointer to the object that is the object is passed to a function indirectly using the pointer.

But in any case the function definition is bad. It can be defined much simpler and without undefined behavior when a memory allocation will fail. For example

```
int insert( struct node **head, int value )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->number = value;
        new_node->next   = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

If not to pass the pointer to the head node by reference then you need to return the new value of the pointer from the function. In thus case the function can look like

```
struct node * insert( struct node *q, int value )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->number = value;
        new_node->next   = NULL;

        if ( q == NULL )
        {
            q = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *current = q;
            while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;
            current->next = new_node;
        }
    }

    return q;
}
```

In this case the function has to be called the first time when the list is empty the following way

```
head = insert( head, 10 );
```